# bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object of object having list of Object

Tags: python, encoding, pymongo

I have a class defined in below form

```
class B():
  xyz: int

class C():
  abc: int

Class A():
 bList: List[B]
 cList: List[C]
 iex : int
```

MongoDb Save Operation:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("xxx")
mydb = client["XYZ"]
mycol = mydb["DB"]
mydict=A.__dict__
 x=mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

If I tried to save the object without list of B and C in A and keeping on iex as int then it is getting save.

With list of other object, it is throwing exception even if I created dict of that object

logs:

> File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py",
> line 474, in _insert_one
> self.__database.client._retryable_write(   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line
> 1340, in _retryable_write
> return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line
> 1229, in _retry_with_session
> return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line
> 1261, in _retry_internal
> return func(session, sock_info, retryable)   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line
> 462, in _insert_command
> result = sock_info.command(   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 735, in
> command
> self._raise_connection_failure(error)   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 719, in
> command
> return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 118,
> in command
> request_id, msg, size, max_doc_size = message._op_msg(   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 597,
> in _op_msg
> return _op_msg_uncompressed(**bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <B.B object at 0x000001DD37C85570>, of type: <class
> 'B.B'>**

Any pointer to fix this issue.

- I have tried to create a list and then insert_many , same issue.
- Tried to save the object without converting into dict, same issue.
- getDump also will give the same issue.

**Any pointer or link will be helpful. Tried with many link present, but they dont have the object having list of other object**

---

Update:
The dict object created for

{'atm': 17550, 'data': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, ...], 'price': 17561.3, 'spot': 17530.3, 'total': 1091633.0, 'total1': 28878936, 'total2': 623204.0, 'total3': 23602622, 'total4': 437333.0, 'total5': 623204.0, 'BData': [<B.B object at 0x000001640F695090>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695150>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695210>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F6952D0>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695390>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695450>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695510>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F6955D0>, <B.B object at 0x000001640F695690>, ...], 'CData': [<C.C object at 0x000001640F6950F0>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F6951B0>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F695270>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F695330>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F6953F0>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F6954B0>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F695570>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F695630>, <C.C object at 0x000001640F6956F0>, ...], 'key': '17550_17561.3_17530.3_28878936_23602622'}

### Look like B and C are fields are not properly injected

update the Class A:

```
from typing import List, Dict
import datetime

from B import B
from C import C

class A():
    x : str
    y : int
    data: List[Dict[str, float]]
    z: float
    B: list
    C:list
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: What does `A.__dict__` look like?

Comment: added the __dict__ response.

Comment: Looks like not everything is a JSON/BSON type in the `dict`.

Comment: any idea how we can create dict of object with list of Object

Comment: If you include some runnable python code that shows how `A` is instantiated and values assigned, I might be able to offer suggestions.

Comment: @rickhg12hs update the A code.

Comment: There's still nothing I can copy/paste into `ipython` that will create a meaningful instantiated class.  Better questions make it easy for readers to try the "problem" code.